# JQuery Shake UI problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI's shake effect causes element to run over to the newline, shake, and then run back. I tried changing the position css, etc, but short of hacking it, I feel like there is a normal, elegant solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ShhER/6/

I want to say it's a bug, but it's probably not...any ideas?

Comment: it works pretty well in the fiddle. can't you change the distance of the shaking on the x axis? i havent used that effect and cant remember the documentation

Comment: no, it takes a parameter but regardless, it always goes far left, then shakes that parameter's distance. here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/ShhER/6/. Just hit refresh and you'll notice the shaking issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element being animated should be block level, or have `display: block` explicitly on it.

I set `display: block`, and then adjusted the label's css accordingly. It worked fine.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ShhER/3/).

Comment: This would work great but now I can't have two elements next to each other (which I do in my main code). http://jsfiddle.net/ShhER/6/ (I removed the display:block here)

Answer (score 1):

I found that jQuery adding wrapper to the element with class `ui-effects-wrapper` So adding this css solved my problem.

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
        display:inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just debug the jQuery UI Shake effect and found that the plugin creates a wrapper to the element that will use the effect. This wrapper is needed in order to apply the jQuery animate function with the Shake given attributes.

I fixed this by adding a with of 100% to the Wrapper. On my case I have something like this:

```
<div class="errorBox nameBox" style="position: absolute; top: 352px; left: 948.5px; display: block; width: 100%">
   <div class="errorArrow"></div>
   <div class="errorDescription">Type your name</div>
</div>
```

Regards.!!